# Track human orientation?

Tags: ros, openni, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My question is quite simple. I want to know if there is a ROS package out there that is compatible with ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 that (preferably) uses point-cloud to detect "human orientation", i.e whether a human is sitting, standing, etc.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262742/track-human-orientation?/) by [Tex](https://answers.ros.org/users/30438/tex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on 2017-10-24**:
Hi,
Have you found a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! There exists the openni_tracker package that can detect humans and works with the ASUS XTion Pro Live as well as the MS Kinect. It publishes detected limbs as tf frames (i.e. head, torso, right hand, left leg, and so on). Probably you'll have some issues in retrieving the libraries to set it working, cause the openni libraries are no more available on the site.
The openni_tracker node publishes only the frames of deteted human limbs Also, it publishes only the position of the frames but not the orientation. If you are interested also in the detected point cloud or in the RGB, take a look at [this](https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker).

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2017-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0